# opencpu returns numbers with max 5 digits

Tags: r, opencpu, rjsonio

I noticed that if I return my R results that numbers are limited to 5 digits, e.g. 100.34 while R is giving me 100.344523. Is it possible to increase this? I found that you can set the amount of digits in toJSON, but how to do that with opencpu?

cheers, Rico

Comment: See `options("digits")`.

Comment: Hi Roman, I did and this is set to 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass any arguments for `toJSON` in your `HTTP GET` request:

```
https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/base/R/pi/json?digits=10
```

Comment: Hi Jeroen, awesome! Thanks! Been spending a few hours on this searching and reading, but forgot to check your public apps. Cheers, Rico

Comment: PS: we have a mailing list now ;)